# Getting all the codecs for a given container

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat

how do I get all the codecs for a given container? In this example I want to retrieve libx264, libx265 etc for MPEG-4 Part 14 container whose id is 28. I have this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  AVOutputFormat *outputFormat = NULL;

  encoder = avcodec_find_encoder(28);
  printf("%s\n",encoder->long_name);
}
```

But of course it prints libx264 only. Is there a way to call a ffmpeg function in a while loop to get all the codes associated to a given container?

Thanks

Comment: Your code is locating the encoder for a given codec. Container is not referenced anywhere. Usually, the codec_tags member in AVOutputFormat points to the array with the list of acceptable codec ids.

Comment: @Gyan thank you so much for your reply, it's what I'm looking for! How do I get an AVOutputFormat poining to MPEG-4 Part 14 format?

Comment: Ok, I found av_guess_format(). Thanks anyway @Gyan.

Comment: av_guess_format is to locate a muxer based on a string id or filename, not what you're looking for.

Comment: So what is the correct function then? @Gyan

Comment: Anyway your reply about codec_tag in the AVOutputFormat struct is incorrect. It turned out it's not possible for the user to access it. The compiler gives dereferencing errors when trying to read the values into it...

Comment: I didn't say anything about API accessibility. avformat_write_header will fail if the member is populated and one or more of the streams has an incompatible codec id..